# How to setup kvaser canlib for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: can-bus

I already know how to add this for Visual Studio, but I what to know how I could add this for Visual Studio Code. Can anyone help me, set this up on Visual Studio Code step-by-step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found useful information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview).

Knowing that I've already had Kvaser Drivers & CANlib SDK and the appropriate extension for the desired language installed, e.g. *Python extension for Visual Studio Code*, I simply imported CANlib by

```
from canlib import canlib
```

Comment: It's best to include the actual information in the answer then leave a link as reference